# Проблема с решением рекурсии

Tags: java

Суть - найти индекс максимального числа в массиве.

Код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Zhopa {
    static class recurs {
        public int maxInd(int[] arr, int max, int ind, int arrlen) {
            int swapVal = 0;
            if (arr[ind] > max) {
                swapVal = ind;
                max = arr[ind];
            } else if (ind == arrlen - 1)
                return swapVal;

            if (swapVal < maxInd(arr, max, ind + 1, arrlen)) {
                return maxInd(arr, max, ind + 1, arrlen);
            } else return swapVal;
        }
    }
    static class Recursion {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            recurs f = new recurs();
            Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Введите размер массива: ");
            int arrSize = str.nextInt();
            int[] arr = new int[arrSize];
            int arrlen = arr.length;
            System.out.println("Введите элементы массива: ");
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[j] = str.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(f.maxInd(arr, 0, 0,  arrlen));
        }
    }
}
```

Почему-то есть конфликт между длиной массива и индексацией. Заканчивается ошибкой `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
Никак не получается сделать эту задачу.

Comment: `if` и `else if` поменяйте местами в начале `maxInd`, но зачем вам, вообще, рекурсия, почему просто не пройтись по всем элементам `for`'ом?

Comment: Исправил.Не работает.

Comment: @Eugene, что значит не работает? Я даже не поленился и проверил, ошибка с исключением пропала, как и ожидалось, а теперь не работает лишь потому, что у вас логика в программе некорректная (в частности, вы некорректно работаете с `max` и `swapValue`).

Comment: @Eugene, написал вам ответ только от нежелания объяснять, т.к. вы явно не пытаетесь вникнуть в суть своей проблему самостоятельно, от слова совсем.

Comment: Я понял ваш ответ сразу. Я тоже решил пошутить в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите размер массива:");
        int[] array = new int[scanner.nextInt()];

        System.out.println("Введите элементы массива:");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        // индексы начинаются с 0
        System.out.println("Индекс максимального элемента: " + getMaxItemIndexByRecursion(array, 0));
        System.out.println("Индекс максимального элемента: " + getMaxItemIndexByIteration(array, 0));
    }

    /**
     * Мне кажется, рекурсивное решение неоптимальным для данной задачи,
     * но тем не менее:
     */
    private static int getMaxItemIndexByRecursion(int[] array, int startIndex) {
        if (startIndex >= array.length - 1) {
            return array.length - 1;
        }

        int maxItemIndex = getMaxItemIndexByRecursion(array, startIndex + 1);
        if (array[maxItemIndex] < array[startIndex]) {
            maxItemIndex = startIndex;
        }
        return maxItemIndex;
    }

    /** Банальным перебором в цикле эту задачу решать куда удобнее: */
    private static int getMaxItemIndexByIteration(int[] array, int startIndex) {
        int maxItemIndex = startIndex;
        int maxItemValue = array[maxItemIndex];
        for (int i = startIndex; i < array.length; ++i) {
            if (maxItemValue < array[i]) {
                maxItemIndex = i;
                maxItemValue = array[maxItemIndex];
            }
        }
        return maxItemIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я вот и говорю, что бьюсь над ним уже сколько времени. Вы меня обвиняете в том что я поверхностен. Но вы делаете тоже самое. Задание - найти ИНДЕКС максимального элемента в массиве, а не максимальный элемент массива. Макс.элемент я и сам могу найти.

Comment: @Eugene, да, тут косяк, упустил момент на счет индекса. но, честно говоря, он несильно повлиял на код решения - я обновил ответ.

Comment: @Eugene, надеюсь, что теперь все работает так, как вы хотели? :)

Comment: Извините. Я пока немного занят. Я как дойду до вашего решения, в случае его правильности я обязательно поставлю вам лайк.

Comment: @Eugene, да нет же, мне не нужен лайк, мне важно понять та ли проблема решена на этот раз)

Comment: У меня вопрос. Почему у вас нет, и выходит что и не нужно, инициализации стартовой позиции для цикла? Т.е. есть переменная и она автоматически равна "0" на начало цикла?

Comment: @Eugene, но ведь у меня имеется инициализация стартовой позиции (как вы сами и говорите) 0-левым индексом. Получается, что мы указываем позицию, начиная с которой следует искать максимальный элемент (и возвращать его индекс), просто сейчас у меня в коде указывается 0, но можно указать любой другой начальный индекс, например, можно начать с середины массива (тогда, конечно же, элементы первой половины массива анализироваться не будут).

Comment: Причем, т.к. требуется граничное условие, чтобы не выйти за границы массива, то приходится при достижении конца массива считать, что последний элемент максимальный (т.е. сравнивать больше не с чем, т.к. уткнулись в конец массива) и возвращать его индекс.

Comment: ВОТ! Ваше граничное условие и есть инициализация. Спасибо.